# SQL Data type mismatch in criteria expression

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, vba

When running the expression below I get an error saying:

```
 Data type mismatch in criteria expression
```

The message boxes are used to identify where error happened, it gets to checkpoint 1 then it stops!

```
                    Dim table2 As New DataTable
                    Dim recordcount2 As Integer
                    Dim command2 As String = "SELECT * FROM [Results] where " & "[TestID] = " & " '" & CInt(LocationID) & "'"
                    Dim adapter2 As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(command2, conn)
                    table2.Clear()
                    MsgBox("Checkpoint 1")
                    recordcount2 = adapter2.Fill(table2)
                    MsgBox("Checkpoint 2")
```

The code is in this section of my program:

```
    Try
        'Defining variables
        Dim table As New DataTable
        Dim command As String
        Dim recordCount As Integer
        Dim LocationID As Integer
        command = "SELECT * FROM [Test] where " & "[MachineID] = " & " '" & machineID & "'" 'SQL command to find if there is a usename stored with that is in username text box

        Dim adapter As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(command, conn) 'adapter
        table.Clear() 'adding data to a table.
        recordCount = adapter.Fill(table)
        If recordCount <> 0 Then
            For i = 0 To recordCount
                Try
                    LocationID = CInt(table.Rows(i)(0))
                    Dim table2 As New DataTable
                    Dim recordcount2 As Integer
                    Dim command2 As String = "SELECT * FROM [Results] where " & "[TestID] = " & " '" & CInt(LocationID) & "'"
                    Dim adapter2 As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(command2, conn)
                    table2.Clear()
                    MsgBox("Checkpoint 1")
                    recordcount2 = adapter2.Fill(table2)
                    MsgBox("Checkpoint 2")
                    If recordcount2 <> 0 Then
                        For x = 0 To recordcount2
                            MsgBox("yay1")
                            Dim TestID As String = table2.Rows(x)(1)
                            Dim Thickness As String = table2.Rows(x)(2)
                            Dim TargetFilter As String = table2.Rows(x)(9)
                            Dim SNR As String = table2.Rows(x)(3)
                            Dim STD As String = table2.Rows(x)(4)
                            MsgBox("yay2")
                            Dim M1 As String = table2.Rows(x)(5)
                            Dim M2 As String = table2.Rows(x)(6)
                            Dim kVp As String = table2.Rows(x)(7)
                            Dim mAs As String = table2.Rows(x)(8)
                            MsgBox("yay3")
                            Dim CNR As Short = (CLng(M1) - CLng(M2)) / 2
                            MsgBox("Further")
                            dgvViewData.Rows.Add(TestID, Thickness, CStr(SNR), CStr(STD), CStr(M1), CStr(M2), kVp, mAs, CStr(CNR))
                        Next
                    Else
                        MsgBox("RIP")
                    End If
                Catch ex As Exception
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
                End Try
            Next
        Else
            MsgBox("There data for this machine.")
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Code on button

```
    Try
        Dim table As New DataTable
        Dim command As String
        Dim recordCount As Integer
        Dim TestNum As String = "1"
        command = "SELECT * FROM [Results] where " & "[TestID] = " & " '" & CStr(TestNum) & "'"
        Dim adapter As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(command, conn)
        table.Clear()
        recordCount = adapter.Fill(table)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

Your locationID parameter has to be a string to be concatenated into your select statement. I'm assuming its an integer which is causing your datatype mismatch.

Comment: Thanks for you fast responce, I changed command 2 to this:
Dim command2 As String = "SELECT * FROM [Results] where " & "[TestID] = " & " '" & CStr(LocationID) & "'"
however I am still receiving the same error!
additionally on access, the TestID is a number: https://gyazo.com/5965941b5d3a56678971e42dd5de84a0

Comment: Are you sure the error is local to that line of code? Try getting rid of everything else that isn't required and running it again to make sure the error is not coming from somewhere else in your script. Also, i noticed your parameterizing [TestID]. There's no reason as you are hard coding it.

Comment: Basically what my code is doing, user has given the MachineID, and I want all the results that that machine has done listed in the dataGridView, here is  aphoto of database relationships https://gyazo.com/11d9d441031fc76a8f0338d6f8339eff

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite sure that your LocationID is an integer, thus should be concatenated *as is*, so the SQL should read:

```
Dim command2 As String = "SELECT * FROM [Results] where [TestID] = " & CStr(LocationID) & ""
```

Comment: Hey, I have added some code to the bottom of the OP, this code still returns the same error.

Comment: This didnt work, however On access I changed TestID on both tables from "Number" to "Short Text" and now it works!

Comment: If TestID is numeric, it should be number, not text. If it was a number, my code had to work except if you have Null values for LocationID.